# mi script php no envia un mensaje json a mi script js, lo cual no me deja hacer una comparación

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

En este momento estoy haciendo algo para practicar javascript, ajax y js, pero lograr esta comparación me está sacando de quicio, para poner contexto, estoy haciendo un programa de facturación con inventario, pero no quiero que deje entregar más productos de los que hay, este es el codigo del script php

```
else if (isset($_GET['procesarVenta'])) {
$id_cliente = $_GET['id'];
$id_user = $_SESSION['idUser'];
$consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT total, SUM(total) AS total_pagar FROM detalle_temp WHERE id_usuario = $id_user");
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta);
$total = $result['total_pagar'];
$insertar = mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO ventas(id_cliente, total, id_usuario) VALUES ($id_cliente, '$total', $id_user)");
if ($insertar) {
    $id_maximo = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT MAX(id_prod) AS total FROM ventas");
    $resultId = mysqli_fetch_assoc($id_maximo);
    $ultimoId = $resultId['total'];
    $consultaDetalle = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM detalle_temp WHERE id_usuario = $id_user");

    //todo funciona bien si remuevo esta comparación
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultaDetalle)) {
    $id_producto = $row['id_producto'];
    $cantidad = $row['cantidad'];
    $consultainv = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT existencia FROM inventario WHERE id_prod = $id_producto");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultainv)){
        $existencia = $row['existencia'];
    }
    if($cantidad > $existencia){
        $msg = array('mensaje' => 'error');
    echo json_encode($msg);
    die();
    }
    } 
     //hasta acá
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultaDetalle)) {
        $id_producto = $row['id_producto'];
        $cantidad = $row['cantidad'];
        $precio = $row['precio_venta'];
        $insertarDet = mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO detalle_venta(id_producto, id_venta, cantidad, precio) VALUES ($id_producto, $ultimoId, $cantidad, '$precio')");
        $stockActual = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM inventario WHERE id_prod = $id_producto");
        $stockNuevo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stockActual);
        $stockTotal = $stockNuevo['existencia'] - $cantidad;
        $stock = mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE inventario SET existencia = $stockTotal WHERE id_prod = $id_producto");
    } 
    if ($insertarDet) {
        $eliminar = mysqli_query($conexion, "DELETE FROM detalle_temp WHERE id_usuario = $id_user");
        $msg = array('id_cliente' => $id_cliente, 'id_venta' => $ultimoId);
    } 
}else{ 
    $msg = array('mensaje' => 'error');
}

echo json_encode($msg);
die();
```

}

este es el script js

```
    $('#btn_generar').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var rows = $('#tblDetalle tr').length;
    if (rows > 2) {
        var action = 'procesarVenta';
        var id = $('#idcliente').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.php',
            async: true,
            data: {
                procesarVenta: action,
                id: id
            },
            success: function (response) {
                const res = JSON.parse(response);
                if (response != 'error') {
                    Swal.fire({
                        position: 'top-end',
                        icon: 'success',
                        title: 'Venta Generada',
                        showConfirmButton: false,
                        timer: 2000
                    })
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        generarPDF(res.id_cliente, res.id_venta);
                        location.reload();
                    }, 300);
                } else {
                    Swal.fire({
                        position: 'top-end',
                        icon: 'error',
                        title: 'Error al generar la venta',
                        showConfirmButton: false,
                        timer: 2000
                    })
                }
            },
            error: function (error) {

            }
        });
    }else{
        Swal.fire({
            position: 'top-end',
            icon: 'warning',
            title: 'No hay producto para generar la venta',
            showConfirmButton: false,
            timer: 2000
        })
    }
});
```

mi problema es que mientras tenga la comparación e introduzco un producto que si se debe permitir me sale este error
[image: error]

Y si no se debe permitir, me lo acepta como valido (no se envia la respuesta 'error') pero no se envía ningún dato a la base de datos, no se que hacer aquí.

Comment: Pon un `console.log(response);` dentro del `success` antes de hacer el `JSON.parse`, y dinos qué muestra. Todo apunta a que desde PHP dejas escapar contenido adicional que está invalidando el JSON, también coloca tu contenido PHP completo pulsando en [edit] para revisarlo. Cuando esperas un JSON del lado del cliente, debes controlar que en el servidor no se escape otro tipo de contenido que dañaría el JSON.

Comment: Muchas gracias @A.Cedano, encontré el problema, resulta que el codigo escapa el codigo de error de la pagina que te dice si la variable está indefinida, ya solucionando esa variable se arregló todo